# How to print any flavour(text,word,pdf,image,etc..) of file from java program?

Tags: java

I need a Java program that prints any file to the default/selected printer (actually I am using RICOH universal PostScript printer that prints any file to a PostScript file). Furthermore I will read that stream from the printer and write it to a PostScript file. I already tried below sample program from google, but when I am getting the PostScript file it is in some unknown format.

```
public class PrintToFileWithJava {
    private static boolean jobRunning = true;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("Authentication in Hive.pdf"));

  DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
  PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
  DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();
  printJob.addPrintJobListener(new JobCompleteMonitor());

  Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
  PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
  printJob.print(doc, attributes);

  while (jobRunning) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
 System.out.println("Exiting app");
  is.close();
}

private static class JobCompleteMonitor extends PrintJobAdapter {
        @Override
        public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent jobEvent) {
            System.out.println("Job completed");
            jobRunning = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You need to be able to interpret the file to be able to send the right data to the printer - it doesn't just magically know what to do with the data.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is possible in Java but it's not simple. You'll have to write a framework which can read all the file types that you want to support and which can render those files using the Java `Graphics2D` API.

That is a lot of work. You can make your life easier by using an existing framework like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) which can convert a lot of image formats to PostScript.

For printing Word and other proprietary formats, you need special converters. If the application is installed, you can try [`Desktop.print()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#print-java.io.File-). If not, then you'll have to find a library which can render these documents for you.